# How to add a button to a dialog and create a method for the click event

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

In Axapta, How to add a button to a dialog and intercept the click event?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1;**

This line is needed in dialog run()

```
element.controlMethodOverload(true);
```

The you can overload the click event;

```
public void MyButton_clicked()
{
//bla
}
```

**Option 2;**

Put your button action code in a separate class, and create a menu option, the add a menu item button to execute your code;

```
dialog.addMenuItemButton(MenuItemType::Action,"YourNewMenuItem");
```

Which you use depends upon what you are trying to achieve really.

Answer (score 5):

If you are outside the `RunBaseBatch` Framework, you can do it the following way:

**Note** this way doesn't require a dummy menu item button either.

Dialog creation:

```
private void dialog()
{
    Dialog                  dlg             = new Dialog();
    DialogGroup             dlgGroup;
    FormBuildGroupControl   buttonGroup;
    FormBuildButtonControl  buttonControl;

    dlgGroup        = dlg.addGroup('ButtonGroup');
    buttonGroup     = dlg.formBuildDesign().control(dlgGroup.formBuildGroup().id());
    buttonControl   = buttonGroup.addControl(FormControlType::Button, 'A Button');

    buttonControl.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormButtonControl, clicked), 
                                         methodStr(MyClass, myClickedMethod), 
                                         this);

    dlg.run();
}
```

Method for override click:

```
private void myClickedMethod(FormButtonControl _formButtonControl)
{
    info('hello world');
}
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew nice advice!